# Checkbox button requires two clicks

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins

community!

I can't figure out the problem. The checkbox buttons on this cost calculator require two clicks for it to register. Any ideas?

https://stylishcostcalculator.com/templates/web-developer-calculator/

Please remove to click the circle (checkbox) and to the square one.
https://prnt.sc/rx1j2g

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome and it takes two clicks to activate the checkbox. This is only after the first one is clicked. Meaning, it will work for the first button you activate, then it takes two clicks.

Comment: Oh. I see. But it is incorrect to use radiobox like checkbox. I think, the problem is in input type radio.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this now.. Any idea why I'm getting so many downvotes? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I think, it's because your question i not quite useful for the community. And there is too few context to help you to figure your issue out.

Comment: Here, i have made my last comment as an answer, You can mark it as a correct if it is useful.

Comment: the error is in your javascript, I tried to review it but for some reason I couldnt access it. once javascript is blocked there is only one click need it in each box. What it looks like to me is that you have a function listening for clicks on this type of elements that is not allowing you to click it once after the first is done. Good luck1

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is incorrect to use radiobox like checkbox. I think, the problem is in input type="radio". Try to switch it to type="checkbox".